# Store intermediate values in recursive function

Tags: matlab, recursion

I am using a recursive function but I would like to store all intermediate values for cp and axial. But I can not figure it out

```
[cp,axial]=powerCoefficient(nturbines)

function [cp,axial]=powerCoefficient(iturbines)
if iturbines==0
    cp=0;
    axial=0;
else
    syms a
    expression=matlabFunction(4*a*(1-a)^2+(1-2*a)^3*powerCoefficient(iturbines-1));
    diff1=diff(expression,a);
    solution=double(solve(diff1));
    axial=solution(find(solution >0 &solution<1));
    cp = expression(axial);    
end
end
```

I would appreciate some help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should work, but will not be optimal with regards to speed etc.

```
[cp, axial] = powerCoefficient(nturbines, cp, axial)

function [cp, axial]=powerCoefficient(iturbines, cp, axial)
   if iturbines == 0
       cp(end + 1) = 0;    % or just (end)
       axial(end + 1) = 0; % or just (end)
   else
       syms a
       expression=matlabFunction(4*a*(1-a)^2+(1-2*a)^3*powerCoefficient(iturbines-1));
       diff1 = diff(expression, a);
       solution = double(solve(diff1));
       axial(end + 1) = solution(find(solution > 0 & solution < 1));
       cp(end + 1) = expression(axial(end + 1);    
   end
end
```

And it's easier to read if you use space here and there =)

Comment: I says that no variable cp exists!

Comment: @R_user: I updated the answer. Remember to initialize `cp` and `axial` before the function call.